# Keep the order of a multi string field using the pivot function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, pivot

I have a field "Remarks" that can have up to 10 codes pipe delimited. An example of the field results are below. I *almost* have the issue solved by using the Pivot function as shown below. The problem I cant seem to figure out is how to keep them in the correct order as in the remarks field. In the remark below 1|120|482|10 it returns in the rows in order 1 10 120 482 instead of 1 120 482 10. Any ideas?

```
SELECT 
,Remarks
,[1] AS Remark4
,[2] AS Remark5
,[3] AS Remark6
,[4] AS Remark7
,[5] AS Remark8
,[6] AS Remark9

FROM (SELECT 
            ,Remarks
            ,value
            ,dense_Rank() OVER(PARTITION BY Remarks ORDER BY value) as testnbr
            from incident
             CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Remarks, '|') AS BK

        ) as srctbl
PIVOT(
    max(VALUE)
    FOR testnbr IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])  
) as PVT
```

Remarks

```
1|120|170  
1|120|375  
1|120|482|10
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use conditional aggregation instead.  But, the problem is that `string_split()` does not guarantee the ordering of the records.  So, you can emulate this assuming there are no duplicate remarks :

```
select i.remarks, r.*
from incident i cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as remark_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as remark_2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as remark_3,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then value end) as remark_4,
             max(case when seqnum = 5 then value end) as remark_5,
             max(case when seqnum = 6 then value end) as remark_6             
      from (select value,
                   row_number() over (order by charindex('|' + value + '|', '|' + i.Remarks + '|') as seqnum
            from string_split(i.Remarks, '|') s
        ) r
```

Comment: The ordering could get distorted, in case of duplicates [charindex() of the first occurrence] eg. '1|2|3|4|1'. i haven't come across a case where row_number() over(order by (select null))  did not return the string_split() in order (although not documented or a coincidence afterall)